# splitting strings in Julia DataFrames gives error

Tags: dataframe, julia

According to [this blog](https://www.juliabloggers.com/dataframes-jl-minilanguage-explained/) by the author of DataFrames.jl the following line of code should work `select(df, :name => ByRow(split) => [:firsname, :lastname])`. However, I got an error.

Do I overlook something here?

```
using DataFrames
using CSV
using Pkg

df = DataFrame(id = 1:6,
                      name = ["Aaron Aardvark", "Belen Barboza",
                              "春 陈", "Даниил Дубов",
                              "Elżbieta Elbląg", "Felipe Fittipaldi"])

select(df, :name => ByRow(split) => [:firsname, :lastname])

# expected this
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ firsname   lastname
     │ SubStrin…  SubStrin…
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │ Aaron      Aardvark
   2 │ Belen      Barboza
   3 │ 春         陈
   4 │ Даниил     Дубов
   5 │ Elżbieta   Elbląg
   6 │ Felipe     Fittipaldi

# but got this
   ArgumentError: Unrecognized column selector: :name => (ByRow{typeof(split)}(split) => [:firsname, :lastname])
   in top-level scope at Repos/Thesis/src/scripts/stackoverflow.jl:23
   in select at DataFrames/GtZ1l/src/abstractdataframe/selection.jl:493
   in #select#296 at DataFrames/GtZ1l/src/abstractdataframe/selection.jl:493 
   in manipulate##kw at DataFrames/GtZ1l/src/abstractdataframe/selection.jl:558 
   in #manipulate#301 at DataFrames/GtZ1l/src/abstractdataframe/selection.jl:566
   in collect at base/array.jl:686
   in iterate at base/generator.jl:47 
   in  at base/none
   in normalize_selection at DataFrames/GtZ1l/src/abstractdataframe/selection.jl:42

# However this does work
select(df, :name => ByRow(split))
6x1 DataFrame
│ Row │ name_split               │
│     │ Array…                   │
├─────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ 1   │ ["Aaron", "Aardvark"]    │
│ 2   │ ["Belen", "Barboza"]     │
│ 3   │ ["春", "陈"]             │
│ 4   │ ["Даниил", "Дубов"]      │
│ 5   │ ["Elżbieta", "Elbląg"]   │
│ 6   │ ["Felipe", "Fittipaldi"] │


Pkg.status()
> [336ed68f] CSV v0.8.3
> [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.5

VERSION 
> v"1.5.3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reloading my environment it did work. The command works with `DataFrames@0.22.5`. But I forgot to recompile the package after switching environment (I had an older version loaded due to compatibility issues with an other package).